# Aframe obj model isn't loading even though texture files are loading

Tags: html, aframe

I have been working on aframe for a while now utilizing google poly models and came across some models that don't seem to render properly (tried locally, texture file loading as well).

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="chimpanzee_obj" src="Mesh_Chimpanzee.obj" ></a-asset-item>
          <a-asset-item id="chimpanzee_mtl" src="Mesh_Chimpanzee.mtl" crossorigin="anonymous"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>  
  <a-entity scale='.05 .05 .05' position="0 2 0" obj-model="obj: #chimpanzee_obj; mtl: #chimpanzee_mtl"></a-entity>
  <a-plane static-body position="0 -1 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="200" height="200" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
    <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    <a-camera position="0 0 5" user-height="1.6"><a-cursor src="ov.jpg"></a-cursor></a-camera>
</a-scene>

</body>
</html>
```

here is a screenshot of my console:
[image]

link to the model: https://poly.google.com/view/6m3diqGPysx

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, either in A-Frame, three.js, or the model itself. I would report that on the A-Frame GitHub repo and we can investigate it.

After taking the same model and [converting it to glTF here](http://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html), the model appears correctly.

[Demo](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/#model=https://ucarecdn.com/8348e993-2711-4b53-bf72-cd8ed53cc65f/)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think three.js is fine as google poly also is using three to render this on their page..... is there a tweak I can do to run .obj in aframe for now? .... right now we are in the middle of product launch so these .obj is kinda imp for my project..... thanks.....

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a quick fix for the OBJ file. You can use `gltf-model="src: foo.glb"` in A-Frame and that should work. When you view the file on Poly it is also using glTF (despite the download being an OBJ).